# Why would MySQL show a different number of Rows_examined for the same query?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL slow query log that shows the same query was run twice within a few minutes.  There were no additions to the table and the key fields were not changed on any records during that time.  Why would the number of rows examined be different?

```
# Time: 130615 11:35:59
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 32.198606  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 68851
SET timestamp=1371314159;
SELECT * FROM `projectaddresses` WHERE `ID_PROJECT` = 77 ORDER BY `ID_PROJECTADDRESS` ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
# Time: 130615 11:37:22
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 30.030193  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 163319
SET timestamp=1371314242;
SELECT * FROM `projectaddresses` WHERE `ID_PROJECT` = 77 ORDER BY `ID_PROJECTADDRESS` ASC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

This query normally returns within a second.  ID_PROJECTADDRESS is the primary key and there is an index on ID_PROJECT with cardinality of 110.

The only thing I found on the MySQL forum suggested that index statistics were updated, but I don't think that makes sense here.

I assume that the fact that this query normally runs quickly and doesn't appear in the slow query log is related to the same issue.  Any ideas as to what that issue may be would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key isn't unique, then MySQL is just reading rows until it has 25 matched rows, then it stops. There is no guarantee the rows will be read in the same order each time unless your ORDER BY is unique. Rows are read in the most convenient way, so sometimes it may need to read more rows to find 25 that match.

Comment: That makes sense, but in this case the ORDER BY is unique.  The primary key is an auto-incrementing integer.